# SQL Server 2008 Create Table Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a simple create table in SQL Server 2008 and receiving a syntax error.
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio > New Query

Here is the syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE Address
{
    AddressID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Street varchar(60) NULL,
    City varchar(50) NULL,
    State varchar(2) NULL,
    Zip varchar(10)NULL,
    Intersection1 varchar(60) NULL,
    Intersection2 varchar(60) NULL
}
```

And the error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '{'.

The syntax appears to be accurate according to examples found online. What is the correct syntax for creating this table?

Comment: remove the last , please from Intersection2 varchar(60) NULL,

Comment: @Satya in TSQL it is permitted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `( )` not `{ }`

```
CREATE TABLE Address
(
    AddressID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Street varchar(60) NULL,
    City varchar(50) NULL,
    State varchar(2) NULL,
    Zip varchar(10)NULL,
    Intersection1 varchar(60) NULL,
    Intersection2 varchar(60) NULL,
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7557a/1)

Comment: but in `MySQL` it will generate syntax error `:)` hehe

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `()` instead of `{}`

```
CREATE TABLE Address
(
    AddressID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Street varchar(60) NULL,
    City varchar(50) NULL,
    State varchar(2) NULL,
    Zip varchar(10)NULL,
    Intersection1 varchar(60) NULL,
    Intersection2 varchar(60) NULL
)
```

Also remove the last `,`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax for creating table in Sql Server 2008:

```
 CREATE TABLE table_name
(
column_name1 data_type(size),
column_name2 data_type(size),
column_name3 data_type(size),
....
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the first bracket

```
CREATE TABLE Address
(
    AddressID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Street varchar(60) NULL,
    City varchar(50) NULL,
    State varchar(2) NULL,
    Zip varchar(10)NULL,
    Intersection1 varchar(60) NULL,
    Intersection2 varchar(60) NULL
)
```